# DELETE_IN_PROGRESS for LambdaLayerPermissionPrivate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

Whenever i try to build my app in aws amplify, i get stuck and the build fails after 1 hour.

After some research i found out that `Lambdalayerpermissionprivate` is in `"DELETE_IN_PROGRESS"` for some reason.

Is it possible to delete this manually, or how to unstuck it?

[image]